# Brick Breaker - bricks not appearing

Tags: javascript

I'm currently writing a BrickBreaker game in the JavaScript language. Its one of my first projects using the language and I've run into a few difficulties. This is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<script>

var canvas=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius=10;
var a = {
    x: canvas.width/2,
    y: canvas.height-30};
var x=canvas.width/2;
var y=canvas.height-30;
var speed = [2, -2, 10];
var paddle = {
    paddleHeight: 10,
    paddleWidth: 75,
    };
var paddleX=(canvas.width-paddle.paddleWidth)/2;
var rightPressed= false;
var leftPressed=false;
var score = 0;
var brick = {
    brickRowCount: 3,
    brickColumnCount: 5,
    brickWidth: 75,
    brickHeight: 20,
    brickPadding: 10,
    brickOffsetTop: 30,
    brickOffsetLeft: 30};
var amountOfBricks = brick.brickRowCount*brick.brickColumnCount;
document.addEventListener("keydown",keyDownHandler,false);
document.addEventListener("keyup",keyUpHandler,false);
var wall = new Wall(5, 3 , 75, 70, 10, 30, 30);
wall.makeBricks();

function Brick(x, y, width, height, status) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.status = status;

    this.display = function() {
        if(this.status == 1) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
}

function Wall(numRows, numCols, bricksWidth, bricksHeight, bricksPadding, bricksOffsetTop, bricksOffsetLeft) {
    this.numRows = numRows;
    this.numCols = numCols;
    this.bricksWidth = bricksWidth;
    this.bricksHeight = bricksHeight;
    this.bricksPadding = bricksPadding;
    this.bricksOffsetTop = bricksOffsetTop;
    this.bricksOffsetLeft = bricksOffsetLeft;
    this.bricks = [];

    this.makeBricks = function() {
        for(c=0; c < this.numRows; c++) {
            this.bricks[c] = [];
            for(r=0; r < this.numCols; r++) {
                this.bricks[c][r] = new Brick(
                    (c*(this.bricksWidth + this.bricksPadding)+this.bricksOffsetLeft),
                    (r*(this.bricksHeight+this.bricksPadding)+this.bricksOffsetTop),
                    this.bricksHeight,
                    this.bricksWidth,
                    1)
            }
        }
    }

    this.display = function() {
        for(row of this.bricks) {
            for(brick of row) {
                console.log(brick);
                brick.display()
            }
        }
    }
}

function keyDownHandler(e){
    if(e.keyCode==39){

        rightPressed=true;

        }
        else if(e.keyCode==37){

        leftPressed=true;

        }

    }


function drawScore() {
    ctx.font = "16px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fillText("Score: "+score, 8, 20);
}
function keyUpHandler(e){

    if(e.keyCode==39){

        rightPressed=false;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode==37){

        leftPressed=false;

        }
    }

function drawBall(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,ballRadius,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillstyle="#0033FF";
    ctx.fillStroke="#0033FF";
    ctx.Stroke="10"
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    }

function drawPaddle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(paddleX,canvas.height-paddle.paddleHeight,paddle.paddleWidth,paddle.paddleHeight);
    ctx.fillstyle="#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    }

function collisionDetection() {
    for(c=0; c<brick.brickColumnCount; c++) {
        for(r=0; r<brick.brickRowCount; r++) {
            var b = bricks[c][r];
            if(b.status == 1) {
                if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brick.brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brick.brickHeight) {
                    speed[1] = -speed[1];
                    b.status = 0;
                    score++;
                    if(score == amountOfBricks) {
                        alert("You Win");
                        document.location.reload()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    //drawBricks();
    drawBall();
    drawPaddle();
    drawScore();
    wall.display();
    collisionDetection();
 if(x + speed[0] > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + speed[0] < ballRadius) {
        speed[0] = -speed[0];
    }
    if(y + speed[1] < ballRadius) {
        speed[1] = -speed[1];
    }
    else if(y + speed[1] > canvas.height-ballRadius) {
        if(x > paddleX && x < paddleX + paddle.paddleWidth) {
             if(y= y-paddle.paddleHeight){
            speed[1] = -speed[1]  ;
             }
        }
        else {
            alert("GAME OVER");
            document.location.reload();
        }
    }
    if(rightPressed && paddleX<canvas.width-paddle.paddleWidth){

        paddleX+=7;
        }
     else if(leftPressed && paddleX>0 ){
         paddleX-=7;

         }

         x=x+speed[0];
         y=y+speed[1];
    }

setInterval(draw,10);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this produces the wrong type of bricks as they should be small and flat and instead come out big and boxy. Also when the ball does hit the bricks it doesn't have a affect on them, whereas it should get rid of the brick and increase the score. Can anyone see where my code is going wrong and point out what to fix to get the game working?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've flagged your question for closing because "why isn't my code working" type questions are too broad for Stack Overflow. In order to get an answer, you should include just [the smallest amount of code required to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Suggested reading: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Declare variables before use.

The code has a pattern of not declaring loop variables, which result in them being created as global properties of the `window` object of the same name. They could interfere with each other if the same loop variable is used in different functions. This applies to both standard and `for...of` loop usage.

Going through the code, there are four issues (bugs) that either prevent the posted code working or prevent getting it working:

1. `r` and `c` are set to column and row instead of row and column in Wall objects' `makeBricks` method:

   ```
   for(c=0; c < this.numRows; c++) {
       this.bricks[c] = [];
       for(r=0; r < this.numCols; r++) {
   ```

   should have `numRows` and `numCols` interchanged:

   ```
   for(var c=0; c < this.numCols; c++) {
       this.bricks[c] = [];
       for(var r=0; r < this.numRows; r++) {
       //...
   ```
2. Still in the `makeBricks` function, the second to last two parameters for the call to `new Brick` are in the wrong order, and need to be in order:

   ```
   this.bricksWidth,
   this.bricksHeight,
   ```
3. Brick object properties: `brickRowCount` and `brickColumnCount` do not belong there and are not set when constructing a wall. Usage of them in collision detection and amount of bricks calculation should be replaced by usage of the `numRows` and `numCols` properties of Wall object `wall`.

   ```
   var wall = new Wall(5, 3 , 75, 70, 10, 30, 30);
   var amountOfBricks = wall.numRows*wall.numCols;
   ```
4. `collisionDetection` requires definition of loop variables, usage of wall dimensions from `wall`, and usage of the `wall.bricks` array.

   ```
   function collisionDetection() {
       for(var c=0; c<wall.numCols; c++) {
           for(var r=0; r<wall.numRows; r++) {
               var b = wall.bricks[c][r];
               // ...
   ```

Fix those and bricks start to take on the dimensions assigned to them, and disappear when hit by the ball :D

*Update:*

Another bug surfaced, possibly the original one that prevented early versions of the code from working. Have a look at the definition of `brick`:

```
var brick = {
    brickRowCount: 3, 
    brickColumnCount: 5,
    brickWidth: 75,
    brickHeight: 20,
    brickPadding: 10,
    brickOffsetTop: 30,
    brickOffsetLeft: 30};
```

It is being overwritten and set to a `Brick` object by the inner loop variable of `Wall.display`:

```
    for(row of this.bricks) {
        for(brick of row) { // updates the value of global variable brick
```

which could have been written to declare the variables:

```
    for(var row of this.bricks) {
        for(var brick of row) {
```

Note that `Brick` objects do not have `brickWidth` and `brickHeight` properties. My solution was to delete the `brick` variable definition, declare the `brick` loop variable, and to change `brick.brickWidth` and `brick.brickHeight` in `collisionDetection` to `b.width` and `b.height`.

And so full circle: declare variables to avoid introducing subtle bugs.

Comment: Many thanks, most of the code is now working fine. The collision detection is still not working though, I have changed as you showed, so it looks like this:                                                                             
function collisionDetection() {
  for(c=0; c<brick.brickColumnCount; c++) {
    for(r=0; r<brick.brickRowCount; r++) {
        var b = bricks[c][r];
     if(b.status == 1) {
  if(x > b.x && x < b.x+brick.brickWidth && y > b.y && y < b.y+brick.brickHeight) {
     speed[1] = -speed[1];
     b.status = 0; - but it is still not working for me. Any advice?

Comment: No worries, managed to get it working. Thanks very much for all the help